# Check DatagridView is empty(has no values) or not?

Tags: c#, collections, datagridview

I have a 3X3 grid which on creation has empty(has no values) cells.

I want to check whether user has key-in some some data into the cell's or not.

Its not binded to any data-source. I don't want to iterate through each cell and check for the data and break on the first data found.

I want some small solution for the same. As same thing has to be done on many forms. I will make some generic routine or extension method for the same.

PS:
What I have is a grid with three paramter

```
        ParamA        ParamB         ParamC
Short
Medium
Long
```

when user fill any of the data. I have to add it to a collection. If no data is key inned then do nothing.

Comment: Did you intend to add entries to a globally available collection? More information would be helpful.

Comment: What does empty mean?  No value for any cell?  I am asking because from the title, empty could mean collection without items - but here you have 3 rows and you call that empty to start with.

Comment: Its not value in collection I have edited the post

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the KeyPress event or perhaps even better would be the [CellEndEdit on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit.aspx)

The following shows a message box of where you were  and the cell contents(**Correction**):

---

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        string message = string.Format("Cell End Edit: just left row: {0} and column {1}.\n Value entered:{2}", e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex,
                                       dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].FormattedValue.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(this, message, "You were here");

    }
```

For reuse you may create your own user control or create a base form class.

Comment: But if I empty a cell then it will not validate whole grid is empty.

Comment: That is just a concrete example on MSDN. The DataGridViewCellEventArgs has the row and column of the cell you just left.

Comment: I just corrected my previous post. CellEndEdit will have the value. The value will not yet be available on CellLeave

Answer (score 0):

You can create a integer value `EmptyFieldsCount`, and update it every time the user updates a cell.

Comment: I think this doesn't work. Suppose the user put some value=>IsEmpty=false Then he enters a value for another cell=>IsEmpty remains false. now the user empties the first filled cell. in this example IsEmpty should still be false. We don't know if any other cell has value in it or not unless we check all the cells (which is not the appropriate solution)

Answer (score 0):

With 1 column is check box if checked is true then:

```
 Dim dgv1 As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
      Dim headerText As String = DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderText
      If dgv1.Cells(0).Value = True Then
        If Not headerText.Equals("Short Desc") Then Return
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString()) Then
          DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Short Desc Can not be blank ! "
          e.Cancel = True
        End If
      End If
```

Without checkbox:

```
 Dim dgv1 As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
      Dim headerText As String = DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderText
        If Not headerText.Equals("Short Desc") Then Return
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString()) Then
          DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Short Desc Can not be blank ! "
          e.Cancel = True
      End If**
```